# "ERROR: Loading of original wasm failed" after upgrading rustup

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract, wasm

I'm getting the following error when compiling a rust ink! 4.0;

> ERROR: Loading of original wasm failed

It's started happening to me after I `rustup update` and now my rustc versions are:

```
stable-aarch64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.70.0 (90c541806 2023-05-31)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.72.0-nightly (37998ab50 2023-06-11)
1.64-aarch64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issues: https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1139
caused by https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/109807

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this issue by using rust 1.69 instead. Specifically I just added a `rust-toolchain` file with these contents:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "1.69.0"
components = [ "rustfmt", "clippy", "rust-src" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
profile = "minimal"
```